# How to import the web light-wallet into metamask?

Tags: wallets

with the same seeds it looks like it will generate different addresses, is that because i am using the testing node or? If I use the same type of node, I can import the light wallet into metamask wallet easily?

Comment: I'd suggest to create an issue in MetaMask's repo https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues. For them it should be easy to import a new format.